# Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' in Swift 2

Tags: ipad, split, swift2, uisplitviewcontroller

Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x37aa0dc8) to 'Acc.DetailViewController'

I want to call method of my DetailViewController.But they crash and show error as mention above.

```
let detailViewController = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().split!.viewControllers.last as! DetailViewController

       detailViewController.myWeb("12")
```

In objective c
  //   `(DetailViewController *)[[[[appDelegate.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `DetailViewController` in wrong way. The last view controller you are trying to access is `Navigation Controller`. First access `Navigation Controller`, then get `DetailViewController` instance from its controllers array.

```
let navigationController = AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().split!.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationController

let detailViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers.last as! DetailViewController
```